# Query a Lead where MobilePhone or Phone is like

Tags: soql, leads

I want to query lead based on a MobilePhone or Phone key. If any of these matches, the lead should come up. But I am able to fetch the lead with every parameter e.g Id, Name, FirstName, LastName etc except the MobilePhone/Phone.

Here's the query i am using

```
SELECT Id, Name, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Lead WHERE MobilePhone LIKE 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'
```

I have tried multiple phone number formats like:
`xxxxxxxxxx, xxx xxx xxxx, (xxx) xxx-xxxx`.

Can you help me get my lead?

Answer (score 0):

Both `Phone` and `MobilePhone` fields are just text fields, so you can simply use the same logic as you use for name fields. For example:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Lead WHERE Phone LIKE '123456789%'
```

Will return you all the leads that have a `Phone` field starting with "123456789"

If you want to query leads that match a given pattern, try using `_` wildcard: it will match exactly 1 character. So this query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Lead WHERE Phone LIKE '____/__.__.__'
```

Will return all leads that have a `Phone` in format `xxxx/xx.xx.xx`

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. I saw same query was working when querying from **jsforce** library inside my Node.Js server but not from postman or anyother API client. Can you see what's the problem?